# Navigate between pages while maintaining state

Tags: onsen-ui

I have three pages: list, search, and favourites. I need to switch between pages while maintaining state.

I am not using the tabbar because it doesn't handle the back button. The app initializes to the list page. When users click on the search button I do a resetToPage() right now. I tried using popPage() then pushPage() but that brings me back to the previous page first then to the search page.

If I just do a popPage() then new pages get added to the stack which is not what I want. Is there an easy way to switch between pages without using the tabbar?

Comment: Please provide some code so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I think I could rephrase the problem/question as: How does one navigate between pages while maintaining state whilst using <ons-navigator>?